# Can't change MAIL_DRIVER to mailgun in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I changed MAIL_DRIVER in .env file of production server like that:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mg.xx.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-xx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I run these commands also:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

However, they did not change MAIL_DRIVER. Server continues to send mail via old MAIL_DRIVER. I got from controller `env("MAIL_DRIVER")`, and it gets nothing (NULL).

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: can you show your .env?

Comment: have you tried restarting your web server?

Comment: @user1506104 No, should I?

Comment: yes. these are environment variables.

Comment: Please accept my answer as the correct one. Thanks :) @horse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to restart your server and/or just re run `php artisan serve` on local dev.

Comment: Just reboot was ok. But there should be some other ways instead of reboot.